# sbt recompiles everything, almost every time

Tags: scala, build, compilation, sbt

My sbt project compiles everything almost always when I change one file. Is there a way to find out, why the incremental build fails?

```
9. Waiting for source changes... (press enter to interrupt)
[warn] Potentially incompatible versions of dependencies of {file:/home/arne/gitprojects/gameengine/}default-a8a2f5:
[warn]    org.scala-lang: 2.10.1, 2.10.0
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/arne/gitprojects/gameengine/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Compiling 35 Scala sources to /home/arne/gitprojects/gameengine/target/scala-2.10/classes...
```

It is pretty annoying, because it takes a minute to compile everything, instead of just a few seconds as it should be.

Comment: I have this problem in many occasions, too. Something as ridiculous as changing a string literal or a private method, something that clearly cannot cause any dependency changes, may trigger the whole compile. I think it's an sbt bug (I only have experience with 0.12, so perhaps it's addressed in 0.13?)

Comment: Without any information about the file, that's difficult to assert. Is there a trait in this file that is used elsewhere, for instance?

Comment: It is hard to say which file, because it happens independant of where I change my code. I did not figure out a special file yet. I updated now on sbt 0.12.3 and I think it is better now, but I can't be shure yet.

Comment: You should try sbt 0.13.  There's some improvements to the incremental compiler.

Without knowing your source structure, I can't offer much advice.  However, prior to sbt 0.13, if you used a lot of inheritance, you'd have a lot of rebuilding going on.  Any kind of cake-related design leads to a ton of recompiles.

Comment: In general this is still an issue 4 years later as of 0.13.15 though the root causes may be multivariate.

Comment: This is still ocurring in SBT 1.4.3.  For a small project this is not serious but for an enterprise application this can add up very quickly, for example the difference between 60 seconds and 20 minutes every time you run a tool that depends on compiled binaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed Soon(tm) in sbt 13.2 when https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1010 gets resolved. Before that, there is little hope.